# Can I use peer dependencies in my library when my library is depended on with a "file://" URL?

Tags: node.js, package.json

**Update:** I don't know if this answers my question, but when I published `lib-package` to npmjs.com and depended on the published package, the code behaved as I expected. See my answer below for more detail.

---

Here's my dependency tree:

[image]

(I'm not sure if `"^23"` is a valid semantic version, but I've also tried with `"^23.2.0"` and seen no difference.)

I'm the owner of all the packages in this question except for `jsdom`. `app-package` has a simple `index.js`:

```js
import { ConfigurableResourceLoader } from 'jsdom-configurable-resource-loader';
import { ResourceLoader } from 'jsdom';
import { myFromFile } from 'lib-package';

console.log(`Is ConfigurableResourceLoader an instance of ResourceLoader?`, ConfigurableResourceLoader instanceof ResourceLoader);
myFromFile(new ConfigurableResourceLoader());
```

When I execute this file, it errors with this message:

```
Is ConfigurableResourceLoader an instance of ResourceLoader? false
C:\\my-projects\jsdom-sandbox\lib-package\node_modules\jsdom\lib\api.js:321
        throw new TypeError("resources must be an instance of ResourceLoader");
              ^

TypeError: resources must be an instance of ResourceLoader
    at resourcesToResourceLoader (C:\\my-projects\jsdom-sandbox\lib-package\node_modules\jsdom\lib\api.js:321:15)
    at transformOptions (C:\\my-projects\jsdom-sandbox\lib-package\node_modules\jsdom\lib\api.js:263:46)
    at new JSDOM (C:\\my-projects\jsdom-sandbox\lib-package\node_modules\jsdom\lib\api.js:34:15)
    at JSDOM.fromFile (C:\\my-projects\jsdom-sandbox\lib-package\node_modules\jsdom\lib\api.js:152:12)
```

The main point of my confusion is this path in the error message: `C:\\my-projects\jsdom-sandbox\**lib**-package\node_modules\jsdom\lib\api.js:321:15`. [I thought the point of a peerDependency is to make `app-package` use its own `jsdom`, but this looks like it's using `lib-package`'s instead](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies).

I am assuming this is causing the error message in the first place but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Am I using peer dependencies incorrectly or do they not work when depending on a package via "file://..."?

I've built these projects on github to let others inspect the entire code base: https://github.com/DanKaplanSES/jsdom-sandbox/tree/lib-has-peer-dependency-and-lib-is-file-dependency-so

Here are the package.json files of these projects.

#### app-package ./package.json

```
{
  "name": "app-package",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A simple sandbox for playing around with jsdom.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run exec && jasmine --config=\"spec/support/jasmine-spec.json\"",
    "exec": "node index.js",
    "lint": "eslint '**/*.(js|ts)' --fix"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@prettier/sync": "^0.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^5.1.4",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.29",
    "@types/jsdom": "^21.1.6",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-no-floating-promise": "^1.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "jasmine": "^5.1.0",
    "jsdom": "^23.2.0",
    "jsdom-configurable-resource-loader": "^0.0.8",
    "lib-package": "file:../lib-package",
    "prettier": "^3.2.2"
  }
}
```

#### lib-package ./package.json

```
{
  "name": "lib-package",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A simple sandbox for playing around with jsdom.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run exec && jasmine --config=\"spec/support/jasmine-spec.json\"",
    "exec": "node index.js",
    "lint": "eslint '**/*.(js|ts)' --fix"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@prettier/sync": "^0.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^5.1.4",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.29",
    "@types/jsdom": "^21.1.6",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-no-floating-promise": "^1.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "jasmine": "^5.1.0",
    "prettier": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "jsdom": "^23"
  }
}
```

#### jsdom-configurable-resource-loader ./package.json

```json
{
  "name": "jsdom-configurable-resource-loader",
  "description": "A JSDOM ResourceLoader with configuration options to whitelist and blacklist resources.",
  "version": "0.0.8",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.mjs",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "license": "MIT",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "compile-typescript": "tsup-node",
    "build": "tsup-node",
    "test": "jasmine --config=\"spec/support/jasmine-spec.json\"",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "jsdom",
    "resourceloader",
    "resource-loader"
  ],
  "author": {
    "name": "Daniel Kaplan",
    "email": "daniel.kaplan@SleepEasySoftware.com"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "5.1.4",
    "@types/jsdom": "21.1.6",
    "@types/sinon": "^17.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "6.17.0",
    "eslint": "8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "5.1.2",
    "jasmine": "5.1.0",
    "sinon": "^17.0.1",
    "ts-node": "10.9.2",
    "tslib": "2.6.2",
    "tsup": "8.0.1",
    "typescript": "5.3.3"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "canvas": "2",
    "jsdom": "^23"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `npm install` will create symlinks for `file:` protocol dependencies. [`npm install --install-links` will install them as regular dependencies instead of links](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-install#install-links), solving the problem.

I have a feeling there's more going on here than I realize:

1. It feels kind of arbitrary that if my link is using a peer dependency, then I *need* `--install-links` to get the documented behavior of peerDependencies.
2. I'm developing on Windows and it does not have real symlinks. That might be playing a role here.

   1. Maybe Linux would have worked as expected in the original question.
3. Even though my answer solves the problem, the original behavior could be a bug. I've created an issue here: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/7143

Regardless, this is at least one of many ways to solve the problem, so I'm posting it as an answer.